# Definite Integration involving exponential and trigonometric function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to do the following integration using *Mathematica*, but failed miserably.

```
Integrate[Exp[I q Cos[θ]]/(a - b Sin[θ]), {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

I need some help or a hint.

Comment: Are you certain that this has an analytic form for all `a`, `b`, and `q`?

Comment: I am not very  sure whether there is any analytical form but I need to do another integral after this on q, and I do not want to do numerical integration if the integral can be done analytically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Integrate[Exp[I q Cos[θ]]/(a - b Sin[θ]), {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

Whenever one faces hard integral, it is good to break it down to smaller parts to try to find which is the problem part within the original integral.

\begin{align*}
I  & =\int\frac{e^{iq\cos\theta}}{a-b\sin\theta}d\theta\\
I  & =\int\frac{\cos\left(  q\cos\theta\right)  +i\sin\left(  q\cos
\theta\right)  }{a-b\sin\theta}d\theta\\
I  & =\int\frac{\cos\left(  q\cos\theta\right)  }{a-b\sin\theta}d\theta
+i\int\frac{\sin\left(  q\cos\theta\right)  }{a-b\sin\theta}d\theta\\
I  & =I_{1}+I_{2}%
\end{align*}

Looking at $I_{2}$

$$
I_{2}=\int\frac{\cos\left(  q\cos\theta\right)  }{a-b\sin\theta}d\theta
$$

This seems not to have antiderivative, at least Mathematica can't solve it. Even this
$$
I_{2}=\int\cos\left(  q\cos\theta\right)  d\theta
$$

Mathematica can't be solved. i.e. there is no function whose derivative is $\cos\left(
q\cos\theta\right)  $. Even this $
\int\cos\left( \cos\theta\right)  d\theta
$ can't be solved.

So before trying to solve $\int\frac{e^{iq\cos\theta}}{a-b\sin\theta}
d\theta\,$, one needs to try to solve $\int\cos\left( q\cos\theta\right)  d\theta$.

I tried Rubi also and it can't solve $\int\cos\left(q\cos\theta\right)  d\theta$ nor $\int\cos\left(\cos\theta\right)  d\theta$

So I would say, your original integral has no analytical anti-derivative.

Comment: MMA is able to find a closed-form antiderivative for the definite integral: `Integrate[Cos[q Cos[t]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}] = ConditionalExpression[2 \[Pi] BesselJ[0, Abs[q]], q \[Element] Reals]`; but not for `Integrate[Cos[q Cos[t]]/(a - b Sin[t]), {t, 0, 2*Pi}]`